# Using C# program how to execute cmd prompt commands

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ShellExecute equivalent in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258416/shellexecute-equivalent-in-net)
>   [Execute CMD command from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255909/execute-cmd-command-from-code)

Say for example i want to unhide all files and folders in a drive for this in command prompt we use this command
**attrib -s -h -r -a /s /d i:*.***
How to make this execute in a C# program.

Answer (score 1):

You could of course do it [programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx), but the quick and dirty solution is

```
Process.Start("attrib", "-s -h -r -a /s /d i:*.*");
```