# Rename in bulk C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm developing a C# app that needs to rename a group of files that are in the same folder to add an extension (so if there's a file called `myFile`, it's file name changes into `myFile.ext`). How can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing Batch File in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If you want to rename a file without using the command line utility like REN you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: @devRicher: I think he is better off coding it in C# instead of running batch file. The mention of batch is just a way to clarify the intent.

Comment: @dani The post explains how to run a batch command.

Comment: @devRicher I don't want to run a batch file from my c# app, i just want to know how I can achieve the same results with c#

Comment: Have you even taken a look at the question, or just on the title? Look at the question, the first answer perfectly explains how to run batch commands without creating batch files. @Hyblocker

Comment: @Steve Thanks, but what I want is to rename all files in a folder. sorry for not clarifying this in the original post :|

Comment: @devRicher Sorry. just looked at it. It is good, but I need to run it from a specific folder, like: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\myfolder

Comment: You just need a call to DirectoryGetFiles then loop

Comment: @devRicher ??? How?

Comment: If its so hard for you, why don't you just create a batch file, run it, then delete it? It's only 3 lines and perfect if you have no idea what to do here. @Hyblocker

Comment: @dev Richer Managed

Comment: You can do all this by starting a cmd process http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255909/execute-cmd-command-from-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to find a way. But for those who need help:

```
foreach (var srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(tmppath))
{
  //To customize for yourself:
  //replace "tmppath" with what ever you want
  File.Move(srcPath, srcPath+".jpg");
}
```